# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a promise

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I got error of `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a promise`

```
const p = Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve('ok')
})

p.then(resp => console.log(resp))
```

https://jsbin.com/daluquxira/edit?js,console,output

what's wrong with above code?

Comment: you are forgot `new`

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You need to instantiate the `Promise`.

In this case:

```js
const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve('ok')
})

p.then(resp => console.log(resp))
```

Comment: new? is that for es6 only? I used to use bluebird, new is optional, that's just for new instance, what about es6?

Comment: AFAIK,  es6 [always had it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Probably `bluebird`, `RSVP` or even `q` don't need it.

Comment: Unless you need to call directly: `Promise.resolve`, `Promise.reject`, `Promise.all`. In this case `new` is not necessary :)

Comment: @mersocarlin Apparently Bluebird *does* need it, as it doesn't work without. The only difference is that native ES6 `Promise` throws an exception when the constructor is called without `new`, unlike Bluebird that fails silently (setting global properties and returning `undefined` instead).

Comment: @Bergi I've never worked it Bluebird. It was just an assumption from my side (that's why I wrote _Probably_). I prefer to use `new Promise(...)` instead.